# Enable https on aws instance with ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm try to enable SSL on my domain which points to my AWS instance I already create LB which connects to my instance. But when ever I try to access the domain using "https" I always get this error "refused to connect", what could be the reason for this?

Comment: please show your LB setup.

Comment: @Rage Hi, I got it fixed, It seems that I have to register my domain on Route53.

Answer (score 1):

1. If your domain has been acquired from AWS just request a SSL certificate on Amazon Certificate Manager.
   aws acm request-certificate --domain-name example.com --subject-alternative-names www.example.com
   (Go to step 4)
2. If your domain has been acquired outside AWS like GoDaddy or another service, first you need to adquired a SSL cert, for free SSL see [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).
3. Import your certificate to Amazon Certificate Manager using cli
   aws acm import-certificate --certificate file://cert.pem --certificate-chain file://chain.pem --private-key file://privkey.pem
4. Create your ELB and add this listeners: 
   [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuxRb.png)
5. On ELB step 3 "Configure Security Settings", Choose an existing certificate from AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) and select your certificate (example.com) then continue your process.

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned I already had my ELB, but thanks anyway, I got it fixed thru route53. Thanks!